# Haskell (a -> a -> Bool) function definition

Tags: haskell

Hi i m new to haskell and i m having hard time with function definition. In a assignment i need to use this function

```
insort :: [a] -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a]
insort [] _     = []
insort (x : xs) f   =   ins x (insort xs f)
                        where
                        ins x []    = [x]
                        ins x (y : ys) =    if (f x y) 
                                            then x : y : ys
                                            else y : ins x ys
```

but i can't figuring out how to use it..
for me is seems like i should be:

```
insort [1,2,3,5,6] (4 > 3)
```

and thanks you for your help!

Comment: insort [1,2,3,5,6] (>)

Comment: A related question: Is there any function other than `const . const True` and `const . const False` fulfilling the signature `a -> a -> Bool` without further qualifications?

Comment: What do you feel like `insort [1,2,3,4,5,6] (4 > 3)` is supposed to do?

Comment: @kqr No. A parametric function with no bounds on `a` can't look at the values it's given at all, and has nothing else available to decide based upon, so must always give the same answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument should be a function that accepts `a -> a-> Bool`, say, greater than. This function will be called each element in the list.

You should use it like:

`insort [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (>)`

Answer (score 5):

The second argument to `insort` has type `(a -> a -> Bool)`.  This is the type of functions that take two `a`'s and return a `Bool`.  Here `a` is `Int`.

The expression  `4 > 3` (which is just syntactic sugar for `(>) 4 3`) is just of type `Bool`.  Poor thing.

You needed to pass the `(>)` function to `insort`.

```
insort [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (>)
```